# For what values does the improper integral converge?

Tags: analysis

Given the improper integral, $$\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^k\ln(x)}\,dx,$$ find what values of $k$ cause the integral to converge.

I think that I can use the Limit Comparison Test for this. The plan is to let $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^k\ln(x)}$ and show that it is less than or equal to some function $g(x)$ that does converge. My problem is that I don't know how to begin solving for k other than by inspection. It seems to me that k would need to be greater than or equal to 1 for the integral to converge, but I do not know how to formalize this. I think maybe letting $g(x) = \dfrac{1}{x\ln(x)}$?

Comment: The integral of your $g(x)$ does not converge.  It integrates to $\ln|\ln(x)|$.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\leq 1$ for $x\geq e$ (the gap between $2$ and $e$ won't affect convergence).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Cauchy integral test, i.e., since the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^k \log x}$ is decreasing, then
$$
\int_2^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^k\log x} \, dx <\infty \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^k\log n} <\infty.
$$
On the other hand, you can use Cauchy's condensation theorem to decide whether the series on the RHS converges, i.e.,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^k\log n} <\infty \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}
\frac{2^n}{(2^n)^k \log 2^n} =\frac{1}{\log 2}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n2^{n(k-1)}} <\infty,
$$
which is clearly true if and only if $k>1$.

Answer (score 0):

make a change of variable $$u = \ln x, x = e^u, dx = e^u \, du\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x^k \ln x} = \int_{\ln 2}^\infty \frac{e^u \, du}{e^{ku}u}= \int_{\ln 2}^\infty \frac{e^{u(1-k)} \, du}{u} < \infty \text{ for } k > 1.$$