# Is a function tending to $0$ at infinity over $x$ integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, lebesgue-integral

I was thinking whether the following property is true. However, so far I have neither a counterexample nor a proof. So any  help will be really welcome.

> Given $f:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty[$ continuous and such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) =0$. Is the integral $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{f(x)} {x} dx$ finite?

Comment: Check for example this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1190982/42969

Comment: The above shows that $\frac{1}{\ln x}$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks! I was going crazy looking for a counterexample and results that such simple one works.